# React Syntax Error : Expected corresponding JSX closing tag for <img>

Tags: reactjs, babeljs

I'm beginner in React and I try to do a "Camper Leader Board" project from FreeCodeCamp.
In StackOverflow code snippet it throws me:
`  "message": "SyntaxError: Inline Babel script: Expected corresponding JSX closing tag for
Please help me to find out what is wrong. Here's the code:

```js
"use strict";
class TableBox extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            data: []
        };
    }

    loadCampersFromServer() {
     ...
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.loadCampersFromServer();
    }

    render() {
        return <CampersList />;
    }
}

class CampersList extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
    render() {
        let campersNodes = this.state.data.map((element, index) => {
            return (
                <Camper user={element} index={index} />

            );
        });
        return (
            <table>...</table>
        )
    }
}


class Camper extends React.Component{
     constructor(props){
         super(props);
     }
     render(){
         <tr>
             <td>{this.props.index}</td>
             <td>
                 <img src = {this.props.user.img} alt="logo">
                 {this.props.user.userName}
             </td>
             <td>{this.props.user.recent}</td>
             <td>{this.props.user.alltime}</td>
         </tr>
     }
}

ReactDOM.render(<TableBox />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You need to close your `img` tag with a closing `/>`:

```
<img src={this.props.user.img} alt="logo" />
```

JSX is not as lenient as HTML when it comes to properly closing tags.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why this is the clase, that JSX is not the same as HTML?

Answer (score 3):

The message returned by the compiler is telling you there is no closing tag for the img element. JSX isn't the same as html.

```
<img src = {this.props.user.img} alt="logo"></img>
```

or

```
<img src = {this.props.user.img} alt="logo" />
```

Answer (score 1):

As the error explain itself you need to close the image tag in camper component.

```
<td>
    <img src = {this.props.user.img} alt="logo" />{this.props.user.userName}
</td >
```

This should work.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for the JSX error I received building a Gatsby/React/Bootstrap project in node

```
<img src = {this.props.user.img} alt="logo" />
```